# Finding two coupled Euler-Lagrange equations giving the stationary path of the functional $S[y_{1},y_{2}]=\int[y_{1}'^2+2y_{2}'^2+(2y_{1}+y_{2})^2]dx$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, calculus-of-variations

Find the two coupled Euler-Lagrange equations giving the stationary path of the functional

$$S[y_{1}, y_{2}]=\int \left[y_{1}'^2+2y_{2}'^2+(2y_{1}+y_{2})^2\right]dx$$

Here's my work:

Consider the functional
$$S[y_{1}, y_{2}]=\int [y_{1}'^2+2y_{2}'^2+(2y_{1}+y_{2})^2]dx$$

Let $L=y_{1}'^2+2y_{2}'^2+(2y_{1}+y_{2})^2$.

Now we consider two cases of $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$.

Case #1: Consider the function $y_{1}$.

Let the Euler-Lagrange equation be of the form $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{1}'})-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{1}}=0$.

Note that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{1}'}=2y_{1}'$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{1}}=4(2y_{1}+y_{2})$.

Then $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{1}'})=2y_{1}''$.

Observe that $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{1}'})-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{1}}=0\implies \\  2y_{1}''-4(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$

Thus, the Euler-Lagrange equation for the function $y_{1}$ is $y_{1}''-2(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$.

Case #2: Consider the function $y_{2}$.

Let the Euler-Lagrange equation be of the form $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{2}'})-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{2}}=0$.

Note that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{2}'}=4y_{2}'$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{2}}=2(2y_{1}+y_{2})$.

Then $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{2}'})=4y_{2}''$.

Observe that $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{2}'})-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{2}}=0\implies 4y_{2}''-2(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$.

Thus, the Euler-Lagrange equation for the function $y_{2}$ is $2y_{2}''-(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$.

Therefore, the two coupled Euler-Lagrange equations giving the stationary path of the functional $S[y_{1}, y_{2}]=\int [y_{1}'^2+2y_{2}'^2+(2y_{1}+y_{2})^2]$ are $y_{1}''-2(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$ and $2y_{2}''-(2y_{1}+y_{2})=0$.

I want to know if the above work with the answer is correct or not. Please check/verify/review them and let me know if something is incorrect.

Comment: Your work is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming.